# Lowering quality of a ball when interacted with C#

Tags: c#

I'm doing a project where a Petowner can interact with his animals in different ways and I'm kind of stuck. The problem I'm having is with the ball interaction. What I want to do is when using the Fetch() method and then throwing the ball to one of the animals the quality of the ball gets lowered by 1 when interacted with. I'm guessing the ball needs to have a starting value. The problem is that I have no idea how to get the quality to be lowered with each interaction. Could any of you guide me to where I should look?

As this is a homework question I do not want the code written for me as I learn nothing from it, I just want to know where to begin.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Petowner joppe = new Petowner();

        Console.WriteLine("Hej Joppe! Välkommen till programmet för din djurfamilj.");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");
        joppeAge: Console.WriteLine("\nFyll i din ålder nedan innan vi går vidare:");
        int joppeAge;
        try
        {
            joppeAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Felaktig inmatning, försök igen!");
            goto joppeAge;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"\nTack Joppe! Programmet har nu registrerat att du är {joppeAge} år gammal.");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");


        joppe.allPets();
        joppe.Menu();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

{

class Petowner
{
    Ball ball = new Ball("Röd");
    private List<Animal> pet = new List<Animal>();
    private string ani;
    private string favfood;

    public void allPets()
    {
        pet.Add(new Dog(2, "Louie", "Köttbullar", "Eurasier"));
        pet.Add(new Cat(1, "Lovisa", "Lax", "Skogskatt"));
        pet.Add(new Puppy(8, "Lewis", "Kyckling", "Samojed"));
    }

    public void petList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nedan ser du en lista över dina husdjur:");
        foreach (var ani in pet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ani);
        }            
    }

    public virtual void Fetch()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("\nVem vill du kasta boll med?");
        Console.WriteLine("\nFör att kasta boll med " + pet[0].PetName + " tryck 1");
        Console.WriteLine("För att leka med " + pet[1].PetName + " tryck 2");
        Console.WriteLine("För att leka med " + pet[2].PetName + " tryck 3");

        int petPlay = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (petPlay == 1)
        {
            pet[0].interact(ball);
        }
        else if (petPlay == 2)
        {
            pet[1].interact(ball);
        }
        else if (petPlay == 3)
        {
            pet[2].interact(ball);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Feed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nVem vill du mata?");
        Console.WriteLine("\nFör att mata " + pet[0].PetName + " tryck 1");
        Console.WriteLine("För att mata " + pet[1].PetName + " tryck 2");
        Console.WriteLine("För att mata " + pet[2].PetName + " tryck 3");

        int petFeed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (petFeed == 1)
        {
            favfood = "Köttbullar";
            pet[0].eat(favfood);                
        }
        else if (petFeed == 2)
        {
            favfood = "Lax";
            pet[1].eat(favfood);
        }
        else if (petFeed == 3)
        {
            favfood = "Kyckling";
            pet[2].eat(favfood);
        }
    }

    public virtual void CheckOnBall()
    {
        ball.lower_quality(1);
    }

    public void Menu()
    {
        int userInput = 0;
        while (userInput != 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nMENY");
            Console.WriteLine("Vad vill du göra?");

            Console.WriteLine("\n1. Leka med ett av dina husdjur");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Mata ett av dina husdjur");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Se en lista över dina husdjur");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Kolla kvalitén på bollen");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Lämna menyn");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");

            userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (userInput)
            {
                case 1:
                    Fetch();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Feed();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    petList();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    CheckOnBall();
                    break;

                case 5:
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Felaktig inmatning, försök igen.");
                    break;

            }

        }
    }

        public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(ani);
    }

}

abstract class Animal
{
    protected int petAge;
    protected string petName;
    protected string favfood;
    protected string breed;
    protected bool hungry;

    public Animal(int _petAge, string _petName, string _favfood, string _breed)
    {
        this.petAge = _petAge;
        this.petName = _petName;
        this.favfood = _favfood;
        this.breed = _breed;
    }

    public int PetAge
    {
        get { return petAge; }
        set { petAge = value; }
    }

    public string PetName
    {
        get { return petName; }
        set { petName = value; }
    }

    public string FavFood
    {
        get { return favfood; }
        set { favfood = value; }
    }

    public string Breed
    {
        get { return breed; }
        set { breed = value; }
    }

    public virtual void interact(Ball ball)
    {            
        if (hungry == true)
        {
            hungryAnimal();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ball);
            Console.WriteLine("Tryck på valfri tangent för att återgå till menyn...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public virtual void eat(string favfood)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nSkriv nedan vad du vill mata {PetName} med. \nGå till djurlistan om du är osäker på vad {petName} tycker om för mat.");

        string foodChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        if (foodChoice == favfood)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{petName} fick sin favoritmat och äter nu...");
            Console.WriteLine($"{petName} är nu mätt och belåten.");
            Console.WriteLine("Tryck på valfri tangent för att återgå till menyn...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            hungry = false;
        }
        else
        {
            hungryAnimal();
        }
    }

    public virtual void hungryAnimal()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\n{petName} har inte fått sin favoritmat och är därför hungrig!");
        Console.WriteLine("Tryck på valfri tangent för att återgå till menyn...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        hungry = true;           
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format($"{petName} är {petAge} år gammal och är en {breed}. {petName}s favoritmat är {favfood}");
    }
}

{

class Dog : Animal
{

    public Dog(int petAge, string petName, string favfood, string breed) : base(petAge, petName, favfood, breed)
    {

    }
}

{

class Cat : Animal
{
    Random random = new Random();

    public Cat(int petAge, string petName, string favfood, string breed) : base(petAge, petName, favfood, breed)
    {

    }

    public override void hungryAnimal()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{petName} tycker inte om maten hon fick och kommer istället att gå ut och jaga möss!");
        int mouse = random.Next() % 100;
        if (mouse >= 50)
        { 
            hungry = false;
            Console.WriteLine($"{petName} lyckades fånga en mus och är nu mätt och belåten.");
        }
        else
        {
            hungry = true;
            Console.WriteLine($"{petName} lyckades inte få tag på någon mus och är därför fortfarande hungrig!");
        }
    }
}

{

class Ball
{
    private string color { get; set; }
    private int quality;


    public Ball(string _color)
    {
        color = _color;
    }

    public void lower_quality(int _quality)
    {
        quality = _quality;
        quality = 100;
        Console.WriteLine($"Kvaliten är {quality}");
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format($"Bollen är {color}");
    }
}
```

Comment: As a tip, never ever use `goto` in your code.

Comment: Yes, get rid of `quality = 100;` in `lower_quality()` and just initialize the member when you create it `private int quality = 100;` You also don't need to pass in a quality if it's always going to go down by one. Just do `quality--;` or `quality -= 1;` or `quality = quality - 1;`, all of which do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll try working around the goto.
Awesome @itsme86 !

Comment: And if you really want to use goto (no, you don.t want to...), avoid using a label with the same name of a variable. Compiler has no trouble handling it, but those who will need to read and understand your code will have!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are always setting the quality to 100 regardless of the input to lower quality. Also, it seems the case of lowering the ball is when it is "CheckedOn". Perhaps it should not be a manual request but part of the workflow after "Fetch".

Comment: Yes I figured that out after @itsme86 s comment. Thanks for the advice! Feels like I'm on the right path now :-)